# Handle slow producer with Project Reactor/WebFlux to avoid overloading it

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, project-reactor, reactor-netty

Backpressure is a mechanism that allows the consumer to slow down the producer when it cannot keep up  with the producer rates. Can we do it in the opposite way? This is the scenario:

There is an high rates of requests per seconds coming into the service. The source is Cassandra. Cassandra cannot keep up with the load, however the requests are still coming.

In a Tomcat-based web service, this is more "controlled". As Tomcat is limited, if Cassandra slows down, since the thread blocks, after some point it starts to stop processing requests (200 threads/requests by default) and queue them.

It is possible to limit the load on the producer (Cassandra in this case) in a Netty-based web server?

Comment: It is still a straight (not opposite) scenario: web-server is a producer, Cassandra is a consumer. The difficulty is backpressure is per-request. 

Would you like to limit total parallel requests to Cassandra? Yeah, you have to implement it by yourself or use Cassandra-client configuration if such exist. Is your Cassandra client also reactive or not?

Comment: Yes, the client is also reactive. And what I need to limit is the total parallel requests.

Comment: It would be nice to have some code excerpt. Are you using `.flatMap` in your invocations to Cassandra? If that's the case keep in mind you can limit the number of concurrent invocations.

Answer (score 0):

It is still a straight (not opposite) scenario: web-server is a producer, Cassandra is a consumer. The difficulty is backpressure is per-request.

If you would like to limit maximum parallel requests to Cassandra, you have to implement it either by yourself either by Cassandra client configuration. In your case the easiest way is probably to set up a throttler for the cassandra client: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.10/manual/core/throttling/

Comparing to Tomcat that gives you much more flexibility: 1) you can adjust Tomcat threads and Cassandra limits independently 2) getting out of Cassandra's requests limit will not affect the rest of your application

Comment: Yes, I have this configuration set up. The problem is that I want to have something more dynamic. I did some stress tests and with 250 concurrent requests, when the data returned is small (10 rows) everything is good. When the query involved 9k rows with 100 concurrent requests latency is getting extremely high (seconds). Usually requests don't involve so many rows but it can. If I limit the concurrent requests with a fixed value then the limit is set globally (for small queries but also for big queries). Is cassandra that should dynamically limit the requests based on the current load.

Comment: @SGiux did you pick up ConcurrencyLimitingRequestThrottler? Looks like you can set low concurrency limit (100) and big enough queue size. In case of "quick" requests(small data returned) the queue will be handled quickly. If it does not fit your desire, how would you like limitation to act? Finally, that's inevitable that some requests might perform for long time introducing hight latency, and you don't know which request is long in advance.